# Silverlight Charting - Stacked Area vs Area Chart

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, xaml, charts, data-visualization

I am currently building a charting application in Silverlight 4.0, Visual Studio 2010.  I currently have some area charts which are working fine, however I am currently trying to convert it to a stacked area chart and the libraries / properties for the stackedarea chart seem very different and it seems impossible to do data-binding to a stackarea chart.  It simply does not find the property IndependentValueBinding or DependentValueBinding when using a stackedarea chart, so unless I hard-code in the values it seems there is no way of building this chart.  Is there a workaround to this?  The issue is highlighted clearer in the XAML below, where the area works fine and the stackedarea does not work at all.

```
        <ch:Chart x:Name="LineChart"
                  Height="400"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <ch:Chart.Series>
                <ch:StackedAreaSeries Margin="0,0,20,20"
                              Name="LineSeries"
                              IndependentValueBinding = "{Binding Path=Key}"
                              DependentValueBinding = "{Binding Path=Value}" />
                <ch:AreaSeries Margin="0,0,20,20"
                              Name="LineSeries2"
                              IndependentValueBinding = "{Binding Path=Key}"
                              DependentValueBinding = "{Binding Path=Value}" />
```

Comment: I too tried to start using these stacked charts and discovered the IndependentValueBinding/DependentValueBinding missing.  Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

Define a seriesdefintion, which has all of the binding properties.  Then add the series def to the stackedarea series.

Something like:

```
Dim StackedAreaSeries as StackedAreaSeries
Dim SD as Seriesdefintion
SD.independentvaluebinding = ...
```

.
define all series properties

Then

```
StackedAreaSeries.SeriesDefintions.add(SD)
```